# @implementation ItemsViewController incomplete implementation

Tags: ios

I am trying to code a IOS project from a ios book (IOS programming).

I have seen a similar question asked and tried the solution offered but it still is not working.

In the itemsViewController.m file I keep getting "incomplete implementation.  I can't figure out how to correct.  I have tried to use other similar solutions but still can't make it work.

Here are two files ItemsViewController.h and ItemsViewController.m

```
//  ItemsViewController.h
//  Homepwner
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
}

- (UIView *)headerView;
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender;

@end

//
//  ItemsViewController.m
//  Homepwner
//

//

#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation ItemsViewController


- (id)init
{
    //Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Check for a reusable cell first, use that if it exists
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    // If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }



    // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
    // that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
    // will appear in on the tableview

    BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems]
                  objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];

    return cell;
}



@end
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Also, in your "`@interface`" file, the class declaration should look like "`@interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource>`", since you are implementing the data souce protocol methods of "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" and "`numberOfRowsInSection`".

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Build Log for your product, you can actually see the missing methods you need to fill out.  Here's an example:

[image: Build Log has useful information]

Answer (score 1):

You have declared these methods in the interface:

```
- (UIView *)headerView; 
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender;
```

and have not provided implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be add into ItemViewController.m file

```
  - (UIView *)headerView
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    return view;
}
 - (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender

 {

 } 
 - (IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender
{

}
```

Comment: This will just produce more warnings about missing returns… ?